# Jupyter doesnt run gdal even though its installed

Tags: import, jupyter, gdal

WINDOWS 10

Im in jupyter and am trying to run the following

```
%run "C:\Users\lewis\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\gdal-2.2.2-py36hcebd033_1\Scripts\ogrmerge.py" -f GPKG -o merged.gpkg "C:\ME\Tutorials\1. Packt_books_downloads\Mastering Geospatial Anslysis\Natural_Earth_Quick_Start\packages\Natural_Earth_quick_start\10m_cultural\*.shp"
```

however it says

DistributionNotFound: The 'GDAL==2.2.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application

I have gdal installed and in the location
C:\Users\lewis\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\gdal-2.2.2-py36hcebd033_1\Scripts

So the problem then is that im running GDAL from its source folder but Jupyter is asking me solely for GDAL==2.2.2

MY GDAL IS GDAL SO WHY THEN WONT THIS RUN?! They are one in the same. I installed GDAL using "conda install gdal==2.2.2" and its there and it works, so why is jupyter being so DIFFICULT!

Comment: Please anyone that replies... break down your answer because im VERY new to this and ive spent several past weeks stuck on literally importing things which should be the easiest thing to do... at the moment though writing code seems to be wayyyy easier.